# Scripting.dictionary to c#

Tags: c#, scripting.dictionary

Facing one problem please help me....

We are product development company and our existing application is in ASP, I am trying to send scripting.dictionary object to c#'s com visible class. I am using the System.Collections.Generic class here is my code

ASP:

```
dim dictForm 
set dictForm=CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

dictForm("First") ="one" 
dictForm("Second") ="two" 
SET OBJMSGBOX = Server.CreateObject("DictionarySerializer.DictionarySerializer")
call OBJMSGBOX.ConvertDictionary(dictForm)
```

c#:

```
[ComVisible(true)] 
public class DictionarySerializer : IXmlSerializable {
 Dictionary dict = new Dictionary(); 
 public void ConvertDictionary(Dictionary dictionary) { 
       this.dict = dictionary; 
 }
}
```

I am getting error Invalid procedure call or argument: 'ConvertDictionary'

Please tell me where I am going in wrong way.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Have you registered DictionarySerializer? How do you plan to use it? BTW, remove the "= new Dictionary()". It's a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

object key = (object)de.Key;
                            object value = (object)de.Value;
                            paramsDictionary.Add(ref key, ref value);

Use this, here paramsDictionary is an instance of Scripting.Dictionary